# Write list of numbers to CSV file in Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of 4-digit numbers (1234, 1234, 1234) in Python that I would like to write to a CSV file.

I am using the csv library, this is the code I have:

```
with open('converted2.csv','w') as new_file:
 write=csv.writer(new_file)
 write.writerows(results)
```

However, when I import the values into a file,
[they are spread across rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jm5l.png)

How could I prevent this from happening and have the four-digit numbers all under one column only?

Thank you!

Comment: You should use `writerow` and not `writerows`. Now each entry in your list is seen as a full row.

Comment: hi, i tried this but i want all values under one column

Comment: Then you could try `write.writerows(zip(results))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the lambda method provided inside writerows to print rows

```
import csv

results = [1234, 1234, 1234]
with open('converted2.csv','w') as new_file:
 write=csv.writer(new_file)
 write.writerows(map(lambda x: [x], results))

$ cat converted2.csv 
1234
1234
1234
```

Comment: Thank you! I would like to know the usage of this method and what it does, could you point me to some resources?

Comment: map method for each item in the result converts it to a list(conversion is done with the lambda method passed as the first argument) and returns a map